# Evaluating $|f(x)-g(x)|$

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two differentiable functions in $[0,2]$ such that $f''(x)- g''(x)= 0, f'(1)=2 , g'(1)= 4 , f(2)= 3, g(2)=9$ then $|f(x)-g(x)|$ at $\dfrac 3 2$ is equal to ?

I am unable to understand which concept is supposed to be used in this question. Just need a hint to be able to begin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: If $f''(x)-g''(x)=0$, after $2$ integration we get that $f(x)-g(x)=ax+b$.